# SAP B1 SQL Query for Gross Profit

Tags: sql

I need to add GP$ to this query

```
T0.[DocDate], 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName], 
Sum(T1.[LineTotal]) AS Total
FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
WHERE 
T0.[DocDate] 
between 
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()),112))
and
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE()))),DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())),112))
GROUP BY T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
'CR' as Type,
T0.[DocNum], 
T0.[DocDate], 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName], 
Sum(T1.[LineTotal])*-1 AS Total 
FROM ORIN T0  INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
WHERE 
T0.[DocDate] 
between 
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()),112))
and
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE()))),DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())),112))
GROUP BY T0.[DocNum], T0.[DocDate], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName]
```

I added this SUM(T1.GrssProfit) [Gross Profit]
between these two lines but nothing worked

Sum(T1.[LineTotal]) AS Total
FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry

Comment: which sap product is this? we have [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402154/what-should-we-do-with-the-sap-tag/404098) for SAP tagging. are [tag:abap] and [tag:sap-query] relevant to this question?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.